# Can I use this script to load pages for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to split my html files up because index.html will be rather lengthy with sub-pages and etc. in a jQuery Mobile site. I am using this for an internal iPad app so it doesn't need any cross browser support or anything like that, just cordova webview. I'm new to the mobile app, so will I have issues breaking up my html files and calling them into my index.hmtl file like this:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
          $("#includedContent-2").load("index-2.html"); 
          $("#includedContent-3").load("index-3.html"); 
          $("#includedContent-4").load("index-4.html"); 
          $("#includedContent-5").load("index-5.html"); 
        });
      }); 
   </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
   <div id="includedContent-2"></div>
   <div id="includedContent-3"></div>
   <div id="includedContent-4"></div>
   <div id="includedContent-5"></div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem in your code. Is it working or isn't it? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery Mobile as well. If these are 'real' pages and not visible until user action, why include them at all? jQuery Mobile can load them in via AJAX itself.

Comment: I was trying to keep my question simple and in turn ended up being incomplete. Basically I wanted a simple, easy way to load the JQM data-role="page" on separate html files to make updating easy, while being able to keep page transitions working properly. I'm looking at alternatives as most solutions do not work without a lot of effort. My biggest issue is my separate html files need to have sub-pages on it and it seems JQM wont allow more than one data-role="page" on the second html file.